# Removing unwanted matches from regex expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of strings like:

- Missing image 09
- Missing image 08; P012V004-0061-01 crop again
- P012CR0409F1-1-04, P012CR0409F1-1-05 crop again
- P012CR0602F1-2-01 crop again

Right now my regex expression for isolating image codes that need cropping looks like
`([\w\d-]+)(?=.+crop again)`, which works but returns "Missing", "image" and "08" in the mixed cases. How can I exclude that from the results? I'm guessing lookahead/behind again but can't get it to work. A bonus would be to return the missing images in another group since I'll need them too.

Many thanks,

Comment: Not sure about your "bonus" section, what do you mean? `(?<=Missing image )[\w-]+`?

Comment: Is `P012CR0409F1-1-04` supposed to be included?

Comment: @JvdV yes sorry for not making it clear

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes but sometimes I have more than one number. I ended up using `(?!Missing images?) (\d{2})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[\w-]+(?=(?:\s*,\s*[\w-]+)*\s+crop again)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RdXrc7/2)

Here,

- `[\w-]+` - matches 1 or more letters, digits, underscores or hyphens
- `(?=(?:\s*,\s*[\w-]+)*\s+crop again)` - that are followed with

  - `(?:\s*,\s*[\w-]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of  a comma enclosed with whitespaces and then 1+ word/`-` chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces and then
  - `crop again` - literal substring.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming image codes always follow the format like

- P012V004-0061-01
- P012CR0409F1-1-04
- P012CR0409F1-1-05
- P012CR0602F1-2-01

i.e. an alphanumeric combination of variable length, then a hyphen, then a number, then a hyphen, then a number.

You could do:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+
```

Comment: true but I'd rather adopt a solution that specifically looks for the 'crop again' string so it is more reliable in case of data inconsistency. thanks!